# Save image from result convert base64 string in asp.net core

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

Before i already make method in webservice and it is my coding

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void Base64ToImage(string imagestr)
{
    DbAccessConnection conn = getActiveConnection();

    try
    {
        beginTransaction(conn);

        string DefaultImagePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/c:/image");

        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imagestr);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            Image pic = Image.FromStream(ms);

            pic.Save(DefaultImagePath);
        }
            commitTransaction(conn);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        rollbackTransaction(conn);

        Responder.writeResponse(false, ex.Message);             
    }
}
```

And i got message error when i execute method Base64ToImage in my webservice 
This is a message error

```
{"isSuccess":false,"resultMessage":"A generic error occurred in GDI+.","data":null}
```

Please help me, how i can fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in your code, `DefaultImagePath` is a directory, you have to specify a file name for `Save()` method to actually work.

For example:

```cs
// Example 1:
pic.Save("full/path/to/your/image.jpg");

// Example 2:
pic.Save(DefaultImagePath + "/yourimage.jpg");
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried your suggestion. and successfully saved in the folder c: \ image but the size is 0 bytes. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @ReyhanManuel I've tried with a sample base64 encoded image and it worked, maybe something else caused the problem.

Comment: Yes, I was not careful when inputting the base64 string value incomplete. Now it is working. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Probably you might have missed the format of image while saving, and file name should be complete (not folder path)

```
pic.Save(DefaultImagePath,ImageFormat.Png);
```

rewrite like

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            using (Image pic = Image.FromStream(ms))
            {
             pic.Save(DefaultImagePath+fileName.png, ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, i am forget give format of image. Thank you so much